# Translation reference for Grothendieck's early works

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, soft-question, ho.history-overview, translation

I would like to know if is there any translation of the early functional analysis works by Grothendieck. More precisely, I am searching for translations of La theorie de Fredholm and Produits Tensoriels topologiques. Any reference in English would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that any translation exists, but as the exposition of "La théorie de Fredhom" is 60 years old, I think that there are plenty of better references. For the other document, there are more than one with this name, but if you refer to his PhD thesis, I think that no translation will ever come, as it took six month to Laurent Schwartz just to read it!

Comment: The  Soviets used to translate (into Russian) the best math papers.

Comment: not yet worth posting as an answer, but I am slowly working my way through translating "Résumé des résultats essentiels dans la théorie des produits tensoriels topologiques et des espaces nucléaires", which seems to be a good summary (without proofs) of a lot of his work in functional analysis.

Comment: [here](https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/gpablo54en.pdf) you can see "Topological vector spaces" a course at Sao Pablo in 1954

Answer (score 4):

I have a translation of "Résumé des résultats essentiels dans la théorie des produits tensoriels topologiques et des espaces nucléaires", which is Grothendieck's "short" summary of the major results of PTT. This summary omits many proofs, but it's a good first read!

https://labs.thosgood.com/translations/AIF-4-1952-73.html

(If this link ever breaks, then you should be able to find the translation anyway at [thosgood.com/translations](https://thosgood.com))